# Can I use NSNotificationCenter selector method in multiple view controllers?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I have this `ViewControllerA` that pushes `ViewControllerB` onto the navigation stack, which pushes `ViewControllerC` onto the stack.

From `ViewControllerB`, I can pop to `ViewControllerA`. 
And from `ViewControllerC`, I can pop to `ViewControllerA`.

I need to pass an `NSNumber` to `ViewControllerA` from either `B` and `C` (depending on which controller I'm using to pop to `A`).

I am going to incorporate the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(getUpdate:)        
                                                 name:@"getUpdateForCell" 
                                               object:nil];
}
```

and implement:

```
- (void)getUpdate:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *data = [notification userInfo];
    // pop
}
```

Can I use/implement `getUpdate:` in both `ViewControllerB` and `ViewControllerC`?

Comment: Yes you can use it.

Comment: Please don't repost your questions. If needed, update your original question to make it more clear.

Comment: My apologies, I was unable to get a clear answer out of the responder from my previous post.  Should I delete the previous post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one connections like from `ViewControllerC` to `ViewControllerB` you can use `@protocol` (delegation design pattern). But for tasks where you need to update something not from one place, you need to use `NSNotificationCenter`

So your implementation for current task is right.

Comment: Thank you, that's great to know.  I was going to implement a delegate design pattern but I realized that an instance of my `ViewControllerB` that `A` would use to receive data may no longer exist at some point.  I've got forward/back buttons in `ViewControllerB` that remove `B` from the stack, and create another instance of `B` to be placed on the stack (it's for a game with 100 levels).  So the original instance will lose it's connection with `ViewControllerA`.  At least I would think, right?

Comment: You need to have delegate property in ViewControllerB. Every time when you create ViewControllerB object from A, you need to set delegate property to self (if It's from A)

Comment: Let's say I have this: `ViewControllerB *object = [[ViewControllerB alloc] init];
object.delegate=self;`   `self` being object from `ViewControllerA`, and the delegate from `B`.  If I destroy that `B` instance and then create a new one, how will the `self` object from `A` reform a connection to the delegate?

Comment: no it's not reform. every time when you create `ViewControllerB` object, you need to set delegate

Comment: That's what I thought.  Let's say I'm dealing with a new instance of `ViewControllerB`, how would I set `ViewControllerA` delegate again, given that user would still be interacting with the views of the new `ViewControllerB`?